# Meaning of layout inflater

Tags: android, layout-inflater

¿What is the meaning of the layout inflater?¿Could you explain me in your own words? Thank you

```
  mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If takes your static layout (that you created with the graphical layout editor) and crate a View Object that you can use at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Layout inflator inflats ur custom row in the listview.which is dynamically created with all the times and bind with different data.